# Journal Editor does not respond about status of paper ~1 year

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper with my co-author to a Springer Journal in the area of computational Mathematics.  It has been nearly a year now and we have not heard from the editor. There was no response for inquiries made every 3 months.  I  requested status from managing editor few weeks ago but still with no response. Given the length of the wait and the fact that the journal is the right avenue for our work, I was not sure what are the right steps ( wait more, withdraw and submit elsewhere?...)

Answer (score 4):

Getting no response to status inquiries at all is not normal. Make sure you're contacting the right editor. Unless the journal is dead (i.e. no new papers accepted and published), someone out there is organizing peer review. That someone should be able to answer your question. However if you're writing to the wrong email address which might not even work anymore, then your email might not even be getting read.

- See if you can reach the journal office (i.e. Springer's employees). I don't know what journal you're referring to, but e.g., for [AIDS Research and Therapy](https://aidsrestherapy.biomedcentral.com/) they say at the bottom "General enquiries: info@biomedcentral.com". Try writing there.
- See if you can reach the editor-in-chief.
- If you've already tried and the editor-in-chief isn't responding: search for him/her via Google, see if their email address has changed.
- If you've confirmed that the email address is correct: try sending from a different email address, in case your current email address is blacklisted for whatever reason.
- Failing all of the above, try contacting a different member of the editorial board.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, will try contacting a different member of the editorial board. The journal is Foundations of Computational Mathematics. I have also already contacted the editor-in-chief.

Answer (score 2):

Withdraw. That is far too long especially given lack of any communication as well as fact that journal isn’t even quite the right fit.

But you need to get it withdrawn. Have you contacted the general editor?  Time to escalate.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. After repeated attempts, I contacted the editor-in-chief, but no response. The general is up and running, and paper was not rejected, so I have been confused. I guess I have to send a note of withdrawal email and just proceed

Comment: Hail Mary approach - email EVERY editor on the board at the same time.