# Under peer review

Tags: peer-review

Hi I have a paper submitted to a journal. The manuscript has been under review for 2 years now. I made 2 attempts at contact with one of the editors at separate times last year but with no success at getting a response. I also emailed the other editor - same outcome. I left it alone for a year before again making contact a few days ago. Same result: no response. My manuscript has been sitting there for 2 years. I don't know what to do next: either withdraw the paper or wait another while longer. Can anyone advise? I would be grateful for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Same answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/142485/journal-editor-does-not-respond-about-status-of-paper-1-year/142500#142500 Although in this case, 2 years makes it sound like the journal is dead.

Comment: I doubt that they will respond to your withdrawal request also. Just write the publisher directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Two years is pretty long by any standard. I would suggest to withdraw and submit elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions