Unresponsive Journal
I submitted a manuscript to a journal through it's online submission system last month (2nd, November) and till today it's still on pending submission check, It's now over a month and counting.
I know the peer review takes time but i don't know if it's normal for some journals to take that much time before editorial check is complete.
I already sent an email to the editorial and the email still remains without any response from the editorial.
Is there anything that can be done on my end to resolve this? including recommended actions that can be taken!
According to the answer In this question;
What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?
It says a few work days to several weeks (it doesn't really specify how long on average saying several weeks doesn't help to determine if the delay I'm experiencing is reasonable or not), but I believe anything close to 6 weeks is longer than should be.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/is-my-paper-under-review-or-similar-for-too-long-and-if-yes-how-should-i-reac

Some answers in the 2nd link you provided does suggest that 6 weeks and counting might be a little long and also suggested sending emails to the editor. But again I must emphasize that it has already been done with no form of response from the editor.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/142485/journal-editor-does-not-respond-about-status-of-paper-1-year

What's your field? Six weeks does seem very long for an initial check from my perspective, but maybe it depends on the area.

Did you talk to your supervisor? The time seems reasonable to me. Some journals take longer than others to move through stages of the process.
